# Why can't users closing questions be anonymous?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Today, I was apparently the victim of a spiteful downvote on one of my Stack Overflow questions, after I voted to close a question (this was pointed out to me by one of the other users who voted to close, and received a similar downvote).

Why can't users closing questions remain anonymous? After all, users who downvote questions don't have their user names displayed (at least not to me with my mere 4K rep).

Comment: You need to be a developer at SE for finding out who cast votes where. Even just being a diamond-mod is not enough.

Comment: Well maybe the person who pointed it out is a developer, or maybe he just did a little detective work, such as looking at other users who closed the same question, and looking at recent down-votes they received.

Comment: @Deduplicator - but it's fairly easy to deduce in some instances, including ours (we close a question, user had no downvotes, suddenly four of the people who closed the question have a downvote, user now shows four downvotes in their profile).  However, that's not what George's question is about.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables The last time this happened to me, I checked the user who did this and downvotes (-1) were *not shown*. I know it was the correct user, because I remembered their rep before and after the downvote. Do you know that this has changed?

Comment: Anonymity does not bring out the best in people.  That includes the usage of fake user names by the vast majority of question posters.

Comment: I've occasionally received downvotes that I'm fairly sure were spiteful, but not in response to closing questions. In any case it is disappointing, but in my opinion not worth worrying about: a few rep points lost here or there doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things, it costs the downvoters points and time, and really it's a pathetic thing for someone to do so I just feel sorry for them.

Comment: So you lost 2 reputation points. On the bright side, it got you half of the "Business in the front, Party in the back" hat which you are now proudly and, dare I say, quite elegantly sporting!

Comment: @HansPassant - "Anonymity does not bring out the best in people."   Very good point.   Knowing that you can operate under cover of anonymity attracts creeps, unfortunately.

Answer (score 60):

I think it's good to see the names so there can be a way to let the closers know if you have a disagreement to start a discussion on it.

**An example**

For example, I have seen people close as "off-topic" about using a tool or resource even though some tools are on-topic if they are directly programming related. Having the names allows someone to let that person know why you disagree. This can then allow users to help others understand the process a little better. I don't know how often this helps but at least it is there.

**Another healthy example**

This can be especially helpful if a gold-badge, hammer-weilding user closes so you can explain to that person why it is not a dupe and maybe get them to change their mind.

**Is this really a problem?**

I have closed many a question and haven't noticed any repercussions due to it. I am only one person and so far you have only given two people in one instance. Maybe if we could prove that this happens often then something could be done differently. But if someone loses a rep point or two due to this, is it really worth changing how it works?

**Responsibility leads to a better use of the system**

If you are going to vote to close someone else's question, then you shouldn't be worried about your name showing because you should be able to stand behind your reasoning for doing so. Otherwise, this could possibly lead to too many close voters without thinking it through.

Comment: I'd agree, but mean while the names are standing for the most voted reason, so someones name is shown with a reason he possibly would not support. Nevertheless the names should be shown.

Comment: @bummi I agree that too many people close questions, which **should be closed**, for the wrong reasons but that is a different discussion. And, if someone has voted to close for a reason that is not the most popular reason then it may be that person is one who is closing for wrong reasons. And I may be wrong, but I thought that people who actually **vote** to close have their reason shown but not necessarily flaggers whose names aren't shown anyway.

Comment: I have voted to close 1000 questions, and never received such a vote.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch - it's rare, but I've had a few dozen downvotes I strongly suspected were retaliation for closing a question, and even had three or four users who flat out admitted to doing so.  `*`shrug`*`, not much you can do about it.

Comment: These sound like great reasons to publicly attribute _all_ votes to their respective casters.

Comment: @canon possibly but I only address close votes since that's what the topic is here. And the discussion has been brought up **many** times about not allowing anonymous downvotes but that isn't going to happen

Comment: +1 _Responsibility leads to a better use of the system_

Comment: Normal close users cannot be notified. Only diamonds and mjölnir wielders will receive notifications for `@replies`. See question 6: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236878

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks, that's some good information. It's been said to be any close voter so that's good to know.

Comment: My personal data confirms that revenge downvotes are rare. I have 2049 close votes, and also a very substantial number of automated comments from voting to delete answers. I also comment frequently when I see problems with questions or answers. With all of that "negative" activity, I only remember one downvote on one of my answers that looked like it was probably the result of somebody being ticked off by something I did. That compares to around 1,000 total upvotes.

Comment: I've voted to close more than 4k times; I'm pretty sure that it is way less than 1%, and probably nearer 0.1%, that I've had any backlash.  Granted, many of those date from before the era when close voters were identified ('twas not always thus), but I can only remember one case recently where I think I got a down-vote because of a close vote.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't? Because often they close them incorrectly. It's good to know who closed the question, because you can ask him/her for explanation.

Answer (score -17):

**Blunt answer**

He who casts the sentence should swing the sword.